# Show all messages related to containing h:form using a single h:message or h:messages?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

`h:messages` component inside a `h:form` is showing messages related to outside components as well.

How can I restrict it to show messages only related to components inside the containing `h:form`?

I don't prefer bloating up my code with a separate `h:message` tag for each & every input component.

---

> Using Primefaces 3.4-SNAPSHOT with JSF 2.2.0-m03

Answer (score 1):

You can make an ajax call to only render the wanted `<h:messages`.
for example

```
<h:commandButton value="submit" actionListener="#{fooBean.submit}">
    <f:ajax render="msgs"/>
</h:commandButton>
<h:messages id="msgs" globalOnly="true"/>
```

or in case of primefaces use update attribute in the command button to make the ajax call